# Cannot identify what triggers website homepage to be too wide when shown on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have built a webite https://www.reseth.nl that displays a width that is too large on the homepage on mobile only.

I've tried to search for the error but cannot find it. I have even made a duplicate of the page, http://www.reseth.nl/hometest, which then strangely does display correct on mobile.

Attached two screenshots that show the issue:
[correct width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S0X0.png)
[incorrect width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QeL0.png)

You can see in the social icons in the bottom of the screenshots that something triggers a too large width. But what!? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: On which device (os/browser) is it not rendering correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to first start isolating the problem. If you believe the issue is being caused by the social icons, comment/remove it and see if the page renders correctly without it.

Comment: Thanks - I knew that but needed to be reminded ;-) So looking at the custom CSS, I was able identify code that, when deleted, removed the issue:

 .home #wrapper-1 {
  overflow-x: visible;
}

Comment: :) Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Your very large margins and paddings on your sections are causing this issue

for example, you have

```
#content-block-background-1358 {
    margin: 0 -10000px;
    padding: 0 10000px;
}

#content-block-background-1055 {
    margin: 0 -10000px;
    padding: 0 10000px;
}

#content-block-background-1099 {
    margin: 0 -10000px;
    padding: 0 10000px;
}

#content-block-background-1755 {
    margin: 0 -10000px;
    padding: 0 10000px;
}
```

Using margins and paddings like this causes these issues. This absolutely troublesome and not needed.

Comment: Thanks - above does not seem to affect the site but I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look and it seems to be due to this css selector:

```
.essb_links.essb_nospace.essb_width_columns_5 li a {
  width:100%;
}
```

So in this case each social link is stretching it's container to fill the screen.

You could override the selector with the appropriate width or fix whatever caused the 100% value.

Comment: Thanks - I have disabled the social links but the issue still occurs. I have also replaced the current malfunctioning homepage with the duplicate home page that works ok, but the issue remains. So it must be something specific related to the homepage.